# jQuery navigation mega menu by click not hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've got a navigation menu that I would like to have certain links display a sub-menu underneath, here is the general layout http://jsfiddle.net/hcharge/HGtTz/

Before I've used jQuery hoverintent to display the menu beneath, however this time I would like it to display without the hover and by click and to be able to navigate with the keyboard by tabbing.

I'm very new to jQuery and I've tried to get the menu displaying without any luck, is somebody able to point me in the right direction?  I'm sure this is pretty simple, with a display none on the dropdown-inside and then slidedown with a click or something?

The menu also needs to close if you click outside the box or another link.  Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use tabindex and jquery to bind on focus event than trigger whatever you want

```
​$("li a").focus(function() {
    $(this).parent().find('ul').slideDown(200); // example of targeting nested UL with slide down animation
});
```

it should work like this
and then use blur event to hide that submenu

```
​$("li a").blur(function() {
        // your code here to hide submenu
    });
```

to enable click event:

```
​$("li a").click(function() {
   // target all opened submenus and hide them by its class name
   $("ul.active-submenu").slideUp(200).removeClass("active-submenu"); 
   // adds class to submenu so you can determine easily which is active
   $(this).parent().find('ul').slideToggle(200).toggleClass('active-submenu');
});
```

Comment: nope you need to bind another handler for click event to do this

Comment: ok i think i'm starting to understand, do you know how I can target the specific child ul of the li that is clicked?

Comment: thanks very much for your help, i've tried something similar http://jsfiddle.net/hcharge/HGtTz/ how would I get it to close again when you click out/another link?

Comment: take a look on main post i added one quick example

Comment: thanks for that, not exactly sure how I implement this, do I add that class active-submenu via jQuery first?

Comment: just put the examples i wrote, and finish it as you want to, http://jsfiddle.net/ayV8F/2/

Answer (score 1):

Is this for accessibility purposes?
If so try tabindex

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_standard_tabindex.asp

Comment: tabbing regular links would work, but as the menu is being shown by javascript I don't know of a way to navigate to the li that has the dropdown underneath and triggering the dropdown

Answer (score 0):

jsfiddle.net/hcharge/HGtTz

The following link is the solution for above issue

jsfiddle.net/HGtTz/23/